# Would placing 2 LIGO type detectors at antipodal points increase their sensitivity?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, ligo

I am guessing the answer to this question is no, or we would have already done it.

[image]

My question is based on my (almost complete, sorry) ignorance of whether the mass of the earth would absorb gravitional wave energy, which I presume it would, or would there be a chance that during this absorption, that the Earth would distort and effectively amplify the effect?

EDIT Just in case the comments below disappear,  my thanks to Lawrence B. Crowell for pointing out:

> The LIGO detectors have a scale on the order of the wavelengths of gravitational. They are placed much further apart. It requires two LIGO detectors to triangulate the position of the source in the sky.

Comment: The LIGO detectors have a scale on the order of the wavelengths of gravitational. They are placed much further apart. It requires two LIGO detectors to triangulate the position of the source in the sky according to angles $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell and triangulation would be impossible in the above scenario. I had assumed two detectors were mainly to reduce spurious signals. Thanks very much.